# LINQ, Skip and Take ordering

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I was doing some testing with Take and Skip and I found that:

```
var objects = (from c in GetObjects() orderby c.Name select c);
var skipTake = objects.Skip(5).Take(10).ToList();
var takeSkip = objects.Take(10).Skip(5).ToList();
```

GetObjects() returns an IQueryable generated by NHibernate (3.3.3GA, using a SQL Server 2008 R2 DB).
skipTake and takeSkip contain the same exact sequence of 10 objects.
But if I write

```
var objects = (from c in GetObjects() orderby c.Name select c).ToList();
var skipTake = objects.Skip(5).Take(10).ToList();
var takeSkip = objects.Take(10).Skip(5).ToList();
```

skipTake contains the same sequence as the above example while takeSkip contains a different sequence of just 5 objects.

Do Take and Skip calls get reordered when they are applied on a IQueryable?
I would love to get some insight on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does contrastz come from?

Comment: The second one sounds like the correct behaviour.  Where exactly is your `IQueryable` coming from?  It almost sounds like whatever that is is making a mess of generating the required query on the data source and messing up the `Skip` and `Take` in some fashion.

Comment: Looks like a difference in implementation of both methods : the sql generated may not be different depending on the order of Skip and Take in an IQueryable world.  Which could be also explained by the fact that the "logical" usage is to first `Skip` than `Take`. Your second query could be `Skip(5).Take(5)`

Comment: @Ralf, yes, I left a typo in the "cleaned up code", now it's corrected.  
James Thorpe, the 'IQueryable' comes from an NHibernate query, could it be that NHibernate is reordering the call in the SQL generation?

Comment: It sounds like it, yes.  However @Raphaël has a good point that logically you'd normally skip then take, so it may be argued that it's intended behaviour since it should be fairly trivial to work around it.

Comment: Bit of a stretch to call this "intended behaviour". If a provider can't do the correct thing, it should fail, not do an incorrect thing.

Comment: Well, at least I may guess that while it's trivial to do a Take than Skip on a List, it may be far more complicated to generate such an Sql query. @Rawling I wouldn't say it's the "wrong" behaviour if it's documented (don't know if it is). It's not because two extension methods have the same name that they should do exactly the same, specially when chained (I totally agree that it may really be confusing)

Comment: @Rawling Oh I agree, I'd say it definitely looks like a bug on their part - just saying they may argue that it's just designed that way and documented as such.  I've no idea either way on that part, it's not a tool I've used.

Comment: I tried your example with Entity Framework. There the generated SQL is as expected and the result is as you show in your second example. Strange, that NHibernate generate different--not expected--SQL-queries.

Comment: @MatteoSaporiti, Is `Position` property nullable? Also, are you using Entity Framework? If yes, what version?

Comment: @rdans: Edited the example to add better naming, the order is done on a string field (I now called it name to make it easier to understand).

Comment: Which NHibernate and dialect are you using? There may be a bug in the dialect or in the LINQ code (more likely), but it is a bug.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos NHibernate 3.3.3GA on SQL Server 2008 R2, xml mapping.

Comment: @rdans probably has the answer - I'd experiment with a newer version of NH (it's at 4.0.3) but it does seem like they had issues with both `Take` and `Skip` in 3.3.3.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is due to a bug in particular versions of nhibernate:

http://sourceforge.net/p/nhibernate/news/2013/03/nhiberate-333ga-released/

> BEWARE: In versions prior to 3.3.3.CR1, the handling of the LINQ Take() method
>   was flawed - no matter where in the query Take() was placed it was
>   always applied as if it had been placed at the end. 3.3.3 fixes this,
>   so that Take() now correctly follows the .Net semantics. That is, in
>   3.3.3, the following queries might now give different results:

```
session.Query<Foo>.OrderBy(...).Take(5).Where(...);
session.Query<Foo>.Where(...).OrderBy(...).Take(5);
```

> Starting with 3.3.3, the first query will generate a subquery to correctly
>   apply the row limit before the where-clause.

Comment: This seems like the issue I'm seeing, but I'm using 3.3.3GA, so the bug should be fixed.  
Maybe they fixed the order with Take + Where but the reorder for Skip + Take is still there?

Comment: yes it does look like it could be a different case, especially given that you are using the version which should work correctly. I would be inclined to try the latest version in any case. If they were aware of the issue they mentioned and fixed it, it could be that they were also aware of the issue in your case and fixed it in a later version. If not, then the wording they use suggests that they would agree this is incorrect behaviour so if its not fixed in the latest version, the next thing would be report it to them as a bug.

Comment: you might find some relevant info here in their issue tracker: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3021?jql=text%20~%20%22skip%20take%22

Comment: Tried a brief search before, but I didn't find anything specific.  
I will try again later (and maybe have a look at the generated sql by using the NHibernate Profiler).

Answer (score 1):

> Do Take and Skip calls get reordered when they are applied on a
>   IQueryable? I would love to get some insight on this.

I think the answer to this question should be formulated this way:

**skipTake** is the result of skipping the first 5 elements of the IQueriable and taking the next 10. So for example in a list of ordered numbers from 1 to 20 skipTake would be the sublist 6 --> 15.

**takeSkip** is the result of taking the first 10 elements of the IQueriable and then skipping the first 5 elements of the sublist (!). So using the list from the previous example, takeSkip would be the sublist 6 --> 10.

For the first part of your observation (where the skipTake and takeSkip contain the same 10 elements), this should be considered as wrong behaviour (or probably even a bug) in the NHibernate implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I find that @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2617732/rdans answer is irrelevant to your specific example since you do not apply a where clause after the `Take`.

That said, in example A both `skipTake` and `takeSkip` should generate the same SQL where it it would select the first 10 rows after the 5th row, (for SQL server for example that would be with `ROW_NUMBER OVER(...)` ).

It seems to me that in example B you are trying to perform the `Take` and `Skip` not on an `IQuerable` but on a `System.Collections.Generic.List<>` (which naturally is not NHibernate territory).

In this case `objects` has N elements.

`skipTake` will first `Skip` 10 elements and from the resulting enumeration (which enumerates over N-10 elements) then `Take` the first 5 elements.

Given then the results are already ordered the result of `skipTake`s `ToList` should be the same with the example A.

`takeSkip` on the other hand first `Take`s 10 elements and from the resulting enumeration (which enumerates over **10** elements) `Skip`s the first 5.

So, that's that